# Solve for x - square roots in equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, radicals

How would I solve the following equation for x:

$ {\sqrt{33-24x}}=1+2{\sqrt{11-7x}} $

Is there even a solution, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphical "evidence" (**not a formal proof !**) that there are no solutions:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$ ( \sqrt{ 33 - 24 x } - 2 \sqrt{ 11 - 7x} )^2 = 1 \iff (33-24x) - 4 \sqrt{ (33-24x)(11-7x)} + 4(11-7x) = 1 \iff -52 x + 76 = 4 \sqrt{ (33-24x)(11-7x)} \iff (76 - 52x)^2 = 16(33-24x)(11-7x) $$

And from here, you should be able to continue since it is a quadratic equation:

### Added:

Notice we must have $33 - 24x \geq 0$ and $11 - 7x \geq 0$.

Comment: Only note that any solutions must be checked in the original since squaring can introduce extras.

Comment: I'm terrible at algebra, can you _please_ edit your post to include the solutions along with your steps?

Comment: I think you ask a little too much to @ILoveMath : he has perfectly explained in the spirit of this site: not give the total solution, when possible.  Unless, we are in the "take and go", sometimes without any thanks...